# How often should we expect component upgrades (particularly pipewire)

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, pipewire

I am running Xubuntu 23.04 which includes pipewire 0.3.65.
However the latest release of pipewire appears to be version 0.3.80 and this has not been the only release since version 0.3.65.
So my question is why has pipewire not been upgraded to the latest version in Xubuntu 23.04? How often and when should we expect such an upgrade?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Once every 6 months - with each new release.